# Endomorphism rings of a $k$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $R$ be the $3$-dimensional $k$-algebra $\left [\begin{array}\ k & k \\ 0 & k \end{array} \right ]$. I have two conjectures:

(1) Is any simple right $R$-module has endomorphism ring $k$? (Namely, is any endomorphism $f$ a scalar multiplication by a fix element of $k$?)

(2) Is any proper right ideal of $R$ of length at most two?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the first one, have you considered Schur's lemma?

Comment: It's a good exercise trying to classify all right (or left) ideals of $R$.

Comment: @zibad Thanks for recalling me Schur's lemma, but the lemma guarantees that the endomorhism ring of any simple right $R$-module is only a division ring not necessarily a field.

Comment: What is your progress?

Comment: Any simple right $R$-module is of the form $R/L$, where $L$ is a maximal right ideal of $R$. So, for example, $\left [\begin{array}\ k & k \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right ]$, or $\left [\begin{array}\ 0 & k \\ 0 & k \end{array} \right ]$ are maximal ideals (since, in each case, the quotient is $k$, a field). But is there any other?

Comment: And why their endomorphism rings are $k$?

Answer (score 1):

It has two isoclasses of simple right modules. As you mentioned in the comments, there are those two maximal ideals. Those are the *only* maximal ideals since the maximal ideals correspond to the maximal ideals of $k\times k$, of which there are just two.  So you have answered that part of the question yourself.

The section assertion is trivially true because the composition length of the ring as a right module is $3$, and composition length is additive, that is:

$\ell(M)=\ell(N)+\ell(M/N)$ (whenever composition length is defined for $M$ and $N$.)